# why tamil characters are not printed properly?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I found a program online and just modified it a little, but the tamil characters are not printed properly. when i give a compile time input senetence in the pgm itself, it prints the characters properly into the new file. But when i give a file as an input, it does not print it properly. the vowel mathras are printed separately. how do i solve this?

Input : sentence given in the pgm itself

```
   #!usr/bin/python
   # -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-
   import codecs,os
   import tamil.utf8 as utf8
   with codecs.open('singl','w',encoding='utf-8') as ff:
        letters = utf8.get_letters(u"கூவிளம் என்பது என்ன சீர்")
        for letter in letters:
            ff.write(unicode(letter))
            print unicode(letter)
            ff.write('\n')
   ff.close()
```

output:
      கூ வி ள ம் எ ன் ப து எ ன் ன சீ ர்

Input: From a File

```
   #!usr/bin/python
   # -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-
   import codecs,os
   import tamil.utf8 as utf8
   with codecs.open('syll','r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
   with codecs.open('singl','w',encoding='utf-8') as ff:
    for line in f.read():
        letters = utf8.get_letters(line)
        for letter in letters:
            ff.write(unicode(letter))
            print unicode(letter)
            ff.write('\n')
   ff.close()
   f.close()
```

output:
அ ற ு ப த ு க ள ை

Comment: don't you need to strip "\n" at the end of the line? `for line in f.readlines():  letters = utf8.get_letters(line.strip())`

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi : thank u... actually i have used f.read(), as i changed it to f.readlines() i got the correct output form. (I think i dont need to use strip() as i have used get_letters(). ) thank u.

Comment: oh okey.  I'm glad you got it working :D

Comment: TIL: There is a python module for tamil! Thanks.

Comment: @Rohit what is the module name? how do i import/use it?

Comment: Did you try Open-Tamil  -- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Open-Tamil/0.65 package?

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments the solution to the problem was to strip the newline characters at the end of the lines.

Comment: i think readline() method made the difference, as it read line by line rather than reading the whole file as in the case of read().

Comment: @charvi If you think that the information you provided in your comment above can be useful, then please don't hesitate to edit the answer and add your suggestions too. This is the reason why I made this answer a wiki. Also if you are unfortunately not allowed to edit the wiki due to reputation points then let me know, I'll do it. :)